# Modify WPF dependency property when pressing key

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a WPF `UserControl` with a certain dependency property `DepProp`.

I would like this property to be modified when I press `Shift` or `Alt`, and to return to the previous value when releasing the keys.

What I want is similar to a trigger, but I don't know if it's possible to set the condition to be something like "Shift key is pressed".

I know that it's possible to specify `KeyBindings` for the control, as far as I understood they can execute a command when a key is pressed, but don't restore the previous vlaue when the key is released.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: In what scope do you want to capture those keys?  Within the entire parent window, when keyboard focus is within the `UserControl`, or what?

Comment: The second case should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an attached behavior that you can affix to some "scope" element (e.g., your `UserControl`) that will maintain an attached read-only property that gets inherited down the tree.  Then you can simply add a `Trigger` on the attached property.

```
public sealed class AltShiftHotKeyBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    private const ModifierKeys AltShift = ModifierKeys.Alt | ModifierKeys.Shift;

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsAltShiftPressedPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
            "IsAltShiftPressed",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(AltShiftHotKeyBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                false,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAltShiftPressedProperty =
        IsAltShiftPressedPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static bool GetIsAltShiftPressed(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsAltShiftPressedProperty);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        var element = this.AssociatedObject;

        element.AddHandler(
            FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent,
            (RoutedEventHandler)OnLoaded,
            handledEventsToo: true);

        element.AddHandler(
            FrameworkElement.UnloadedEvent,
            (RoutedEventHandler)OnUnloaded,
            handledEventsToo: true);

        element.AddHandler(
            UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent,
            (KeyEventHandler)OnKey,
            handledEventsToo: true);

        element.AddHandler(
            UIElement.PreviewKeyUpEvent,
            (KeyEventHandler)OnKey,
            handledEventsToo: true);

        element.AddHandler(
            UIElement.LostKeyboardFocusEvent,
            (KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler)OnLostKeyboardFocus,
            handledEventsToo: true);

        var window = element as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
            window.Deactivated += OnWindowDeactivated;
        }

        CheckToggledState();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        ClearToggledState();

        base.OnDetaching();

        var element = this.AssociatedObject;

        element.RemoveHandler(
            FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent,
            (RoutedEventHandler)OnLoaded);

        element.RemoveHandler(
            FrameworkElement.UnloadedEvent,
            (RoutedEventHandler)OnUnloaded);

        element.RemoveHandler(
            UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent,
            (KeyEventHandler)OnKey);

        element.RemoveHandler(
            UIElement.PreviewKeyUpEvent,
            (KeyEventHandler)OnKey);

        element.RemoveHandler(
            UIElement.LostKeyboardFocusEvent,
            (KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler)OnLostKeyboardFocus);

        var window = element as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.Activated -= OnWindowActivated;
            window.Deactivated -= OnWindowDeactivated;
        }
    }

    private void CheckToggledState()
    {
        var element = this.AssociatedObject;
        if (element.IsLoaded &&
            element.IsKeyboardFocusWithin &&
            Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.Modifiers == AltShift)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsAltShiftPressedPropertyKey, true);
        }
        else
        {
            element.ClearValue(IsAltShiftPressedPropertyKey);                
        }
    }

    private void ClearToggledState()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.ClearValue(IsAltShiftPressedPropertyKey);
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckToggledState();
    }

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearToggledState();
    }

    private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckToggledState();
    }

    private void OnWindowDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearToggledState();
    }

    private void OnLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckToggledState();
    }

    private void OnKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckToggledState();
    }
}
```